# Modular exponentiation WITHOUT modular exponentiation

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

Given that $719$ is prime, find the least positive residue of $11^{721} \pmod {719}$, without using modular exponentiation.

So, I know how to use modular exponentiation and have done it to get the answer $612$, but I have no idea how to do this without modular exponentiation...

Any ideas for a method I can try?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT:

As $719$ is prime, $(11,719)=1$ and $11^{719-1}\equiv1\pmod {719}$ using Fermat's Little Theorem

So, $11^{721}=11^3\cdot11^{718}\equiv 11^3\pmod{719}\equiv\cdots$

Comment: Ah thank you ! so simple ...
Will accept in 10 min when I can

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple application of Fermat's Little theorem.

** 
if M is prime, then to find a<sup>b</sup> % M,

r = b % (M-1)

c = a % M

a<sup>b</sup> % M = c<sup>r</sup> % M

**

721 % 718 = 3

11 % 719 = 11

Therefore, 11<sup>721</sup> % 719 = 11<sup>3</sup> % 719 = 612

So, there is no need to perform modular exponentiation if Mod value is given prime.

Comment: This is quite difficult to read, in large part due to the lack of proper formatting.  Can you please go over the [MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), and edit your answer for readability?  It should also be noted that the use of `%` for modular division is relatively uncommon in mathematical notation. If you are going to use that notation, it would be helpful if you took a couple of words to explain what, exactly, it means (for example, my recollection is that the C programming language uses `%` in a way that is distinct from the usual notation in mathematics).

Comment: @XanderHenderson sir, first of all I'm sorry for my failure by not being able to make my solution readable to you. Actually this is relative issue, I agree. For being a student of computer science background, I have got familiar with irrelevant notation instead of proper mathematical notation. I will study more on it.